# cURL acting very strange

Tags: php, apache, curl, xampp

I'm importing some data from external domains successful with cURL, until I tried with this URI: http://www.airbnb.com/calendar/ical/760186.ics?s=29623a93eb0e693c77591a711f082f06, which is a ics calendar.
I can successfully run it on a command line (try for your selves):
shell>> curl https://www.airbnb.com/calendar/ical/760660.ics?s=593cc556438a8f0919beb6107b6f508d, so it's not a network issue.

but my php script (that do return other URI) DO NOT return this. or better it return false.

here is the small php

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}

$ical1= "http://www.airbnb.com/calendar/ical/760186.ics?s=29623a93eb0e693c77591a711f082f06";
echo file_get_contents_curl($ical1);
```

I do think this has something to do with my apache or php configuration, because it runs on appfog and it run with my old xampp instalation.
To resume: all URI worked with old xampp instalation and now just the one from the example fails.

on my phpinfo() i can read:

```
cURL support enabled
cURL Information 7.24.0
Age 3
Features
AsynchDNS Yes
Debug No
GSS-Negotiate Yes
IDN No
IPv6 Yes
Largefile Yes
NTLM Yes
SPNEGO No
SSL Yes
SSPI Yes
krb4 No
libz Yes
CharConv No
Protocols dict, file, ftp, ftps, gopher, http, https, imap, imaps, ldap, pop3, pop3s, rtsp, scp, sftp, smtp, smtps, telnet, tftp
Host i386-pc-win32
SSL Version OpenSSL/1.0.1c
ZLib Version 1.2.5
libSSH Version libssh2/1.3.0
```

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: Both are valid tools to download files. If you don't say what's wrong with them, we can't provide alternatives.

Comment: do you get ANY data, or some error in your logs / screen?

Comment: the function returns false.

Comment: I found that this is probably an apache issue... It worked on appfog like a charm...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL is valid and can be downloaded no problems just by putting the URL in to a browser, so that isn't your problem.

The URL redirects to the same URL but on a secure server, but you have set CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION so that isn't your problem either.

However, the secure URL carries out a javascript redirect to the UK site, and this *is* your problem.  You're pulling back the wrong file.

Try it with the URL `https://www.airbnb.co.uk/calendar/ical/760186.ics?s=29623a93eb0e693c77591a711f082f06` instead and see how it goes.

Comment: it didn't work either, but I was editing the question at same time you  were answering. It must be from my local web-server, a straight forward apache configuration that seems to be blocking this kind of requests. It works for standard pages like www.google.com though. @jgm: Many thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I tried using curl and file_get_contents. 
I tried the below and it works, I don't know why it works and how it differs from the examples above but it gets the ICAL file perfectly.

The url has to be https or it shows a blank screen.

function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

return $data;
```

}

echo file_get_contents_curl('https://www.airbnb.co.uk/calendar/ical/760186.ics?s=29623a93eb0e693c77591a711f082f06');