# Get request with curl works but Net::HTTP and OpenURI fail

Tags: ruby, http, curl, net-http, open-uri

My Rails application regularly polls partners' ICS files and sometimes it fails for no reason whatsoever. When I do:

```
curl https://www.airbnb.es/calendar/ical/234892374.ics?s=23412342323
```

(params #'s faked here)

I get output matching the content of the ICS file. Just opening it in the browser works fine as well.

When I use:

```
Net::HTTP.get(URI(a.ics_link))
```

I get a "503 Service Temporarily Unavailable" response. I also tried the same with OpenURI with similar results.

Why is it that the server is treating requests from curl or a browser differently?

Is there some way to get Ruby to get around this?

Comment: This isn't an answer per se but I don't think its common to use Net::HTTP for API requests in ruby. I personally use https://github.com/httprb/http but on this page you can see other gems that handle HTTP requests.

Comment: My actual source code that works the rest of the time (these airbnb ics files seem to kind of consistently fail) uses open-uri. I am really just puzzled as to why you would get a different response from two different http clients.

Comment: It could be that the server you're making a request to is doing a check on an optional header that curl isn't passing eg the referer, cookie, user agent.

I'm assuming that it doesn't require authorization.

Comment: check this answer out [curl acting very strange](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15095673/curl-acting-very-strange)

Comment: I'd suspect getting "503 Service Temporarily Unavailable" means you're violating their TOS and getting temporarily shutdown. Using `curl` and the browser are probably one-off tests but using Net::HTTP and OpenURI are hitting the server very hard because you're not being a good network citizen. Without more information we can't give you a more detailed answer. Search for "robots.txt" on the internet and honor its settings; That'll help you in the long run.

Comment: I'll take a look Tin Man. I can't see much else wrong. Airbnb lets users export these calendars just for this purpose. On top of that it usually works! I checked robots and that endpoint is specifically allowed:

```User-Agent: *
Allow: /calendar/ical/
```

Answer (score -1):

It's an https issue... not sure why, but switch your url in Ruby to https and it should work.